# Getting Fast CGI Error

Tags: php, iis, fastcgi

FastCGI Error

### The FastCGI Handler was unable to process the request.

Error Details:
An error occurred processing config file.
Error Number: 5 (0x80070005).
Error Description: Access is denied.
HTTP Error 500 - Server Error.

I am using php 5.3 version with IIS 6 version.
I have increased values of Activity timeout and request timeout in fcgiext.ini and also increated the value of max_exectuion_time() value in php.ini file.
But still getting fast cgi error.
Please anyone help me out from it.